# API Gateway: "Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

There are other questions covering this error, but they are looking for accessing query parameters, which is not my scenario.

Testing my simple GET request fails with the following in the `errorMessage` field in the test console:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@6bdf28bb; line: 1, column: 1
```

My lambda function is a simple Java class with a static method `get` that takes one parameter: an id from a path param.

For example, doing a `GET` to `mysite.com/resource/1` should pass `1` to the `get` method of my static class.

I haven't set up a mapping for this because I'm not mapping the request body. The API Gateway documentation is very confusing and also quite light on its example covering a similar scenario.

How can I map a path parameter to my lambda function's parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Just for background, the Lambda functions don't have any concept of "parameters"; everything has to go into the request payload to the function. So in your case you need to use a mapping template on the Integration to transform the incoming GET parameters into a JSON payload that you can give to Lambda.

The path parameters are available in the same mapping template object as query string parameters, which is $input.params([name]) where [name] is the name of the parameter.

So your template would look like this:

Content-Type: application/json

Template:

```
{
  "resourceId" : "$input.params('your_name_here')"
}
```

I put the JSON value in quotes but if the value is guaranteed to be a number you could remove them. Probably safer to put it in quotes anyway.

Here's the template reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

The Content-Type is actually important here because API Gateway will checks the Content-Type header of the incoming request to determine which mapping template to use. Usually in GET requests there is no Content-Type header, so API Gateway assumes that you want 'application/json' so if your template is mapped to a content type other than application/json, it won't work as expected.

---

Edit: more background on Lambda integration

Comment: Does `$input.params` cover path parameters too? I've tried this and still get the same issue.

Comment: Yes it does. 


It's possible the parameter isn't set up correctly? So the resource path is "/resource/{foo}" and then there is a path parameter named 'foo' correct? In that case the template I pasted above should work perfectly if you use 

{
  "resourceId" : "$input.params('foo')"
}

Comment: The content type confuses me here, 'cause as you say it's a GET request. The response is actually just a String at the moment, and the handler method in java is simply `public static String get(String id) { ... }`. The GET request to my deployed version should just invoke `get(pathParameter)`, but I seemingly get this same error message. Furthermore, having set content type to application/json as you suggest and map it as such, I still get the error. Baffling.